# Probability Mass Functions ; Limit

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let A and B be two discrete random variables with joint PMF $P _{A,B} (n,m).\\ What\ is \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P _{A,B} (n,0)$

My idea is that since A is growing to inf, the probability will decrease and the points of intersection with B will go to a constant value or zero. 
But I'm not sure of such a generalization.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $P_{A,B}(n,0) \leq \sum_{m} P_{A,B}(n,m) =  P_A(n)\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. To see why $P_A(n)\to 0$ note that $\sum P_A(n) = 1$, so the terms in the series must go to zero.

Comment: Yes I understand that. The probability of one part of A will always be less than that of the total and since A is constrained to one value of B, stretching A to infinity is just like a 1 dimensional random variable whose limit at inf is 0. So the final result is 0.  
Is this what you mean? I'm trying to explain it in simple terms to my peers.

Comment: I find that putting words to something like this only complicates the problem. The only intuitive way I have to say it is that the mass of $A$ cannot be concentrated at infinity.

Comment: By "concentrated" you mean?

Comment: I mean exactly that $P(|A|>n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.